# Shape of very long wire between two very tall posts (many km tall) which are attached to the earth

Tags: geometry, physics

Consider for a moment a length of uniform wire or chain which goes between two posts of equal height. If we assume the earth to be flat then we can predict the shape of the curve using

$$y = a \cosh \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$$

But if we had a very long wire between two very tall posts which were angle theta apart on a planet which is a perfect sphere then what would the equation be which gives the height of the wire as a function of the angle between the two posts.

Note that in the "flat earth" wire example the gravitational field strength which the wire is in will be constant, while in the case of a wire which goes between two very tall towers the gravitational field strength is not constant. This is likely to make the problem more complex.

Comment: Interesting problem, for sure !

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Are you familiar with the variational method? You need to find the $r(\phi)$ to minimize the potential energy $U=-\int d\phi \ r^{-1}\sqrt{r^2+r'^2}$ subject to constraint $\text{length}=L=\int d\phi \ \sqrt{r^2+r'^2}$. In principle, you then solve the Euler Lagrange equations to find $r(\phi)$

Comment: I had thought of some iteration method, I was considering trying to devise a brute force attack on the problem by breaking the wire into lots of short lengths.

Comment: Are you assuming a gravitational force? Directed to the center? The posts are of same height? Stretched from the center of the sphere? What is the weight associated with the wire? - I am not sure the problem is well defined.

Comment: Wikipedia describes a generalization for general force. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Other_generalizations